# How do we prove or disprove 3 statements together in discrete math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

From my understanding what the question asks for is for us to prove them by

$$p_1 \to p_2,\quad p_2 \to p_3,\quad p_3 \to p_1$$

But how do we actually do this? The question is as follows:

The following statements are equivalent for all non-negative integers $a$ and $b$:

- $a < b$
- $(a + b)^2 < 4b^2$
- $4a^2 < (a + b)^2$

Comment: Equivalent ask for _iff_ condition between statements, what is different of _if_ alone (implication).

Comment: @Masacroso The three implications $p_1 \implies p_2, p_2 \implies p_3, p_3 \implies p_1$ give you equivalence; by transitivity, you can construct the other three implications $p_2 \implies p_1, p_3 \implies p_2, p_1 \implies p_3$.

Comment: This is not what Im talking about @DylanSp. The implications are created by the OP but the real text is about equivalence relations, so is not correct the way the OP represent the text.

Comment: @Masacroso I'm not seeing how equivalence relations are relevant, unless there's something in the source textbook that's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DylanSp then ask to the author of the book, not to me. For me the interpretation is clear. I must be more specific: logic equivalence relation.

Comment: @Masacroso I'm still not sure what you're saying. Saying $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ means $p_1 \iff p_2$, $p_1 \iff p_3$, and $p_2 \iff p_3$. Proving $p_1 \implies p_2$, $p_1 \implies p_3$, and $p_2 \implies p_3$ suffices to prove this, as my earlier comment mentioned. As it happens, we don't need to use this method for this problem (see Jimmy's answer), but the general method is still sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can show that $p_1\iff p_2$ and $p_1\iff p_3$

1. $p_1\implies p_2$ $$a<b \implies a+b<b+b \overset{a,b\ge 0}\implies (a+b)^2<(2b)^2 \ $$
2. $p_2\implies p_1$ $$(a+b)^2<4b^2 \implies \sqrt{(a+b)^2}<\sqrt{4b^2}\overset{a,b\ge0}\implies a+b<2b \implies a<b \ $$

Similarly you can show that $p_1\iff p_3$ which combined (i.e. by transitivity) gives the required equivalence.

Comment: Proving $p_1\implies p_2 \implies p_3$ is commonly used to prove the equivalence of three statements (so your understanding is not wrong) but here I found that this other method is simpler (worked faster for me at least).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is a great and simple breakdown of what I needed.